# Go local module import can't be resolved by IDE linter

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, lint, goland, golint

The code compiles fine, but when using the replace directive for mapping package name to a local directory, the Go linter can't pick this up.

I've tried this on both VSCode & Goland, both has the lint error as shown below. The image is extra information, all code & error messages are shown below in text format.

[image]

Repository: https://github.com/webberwang/go-lint-error

This is the folder structure:

```
/core
  /calc
    math.go
  go.mod
/main
  app.go
  go.mod
```

```golang
// main/app.go

package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/codelabstudios/core/calc" <- ERROR "Cannot resolve directory 'core'"
)

func main() {
    result := calc.Add(1, 2) <- ERROR "Unresolved reference 'Add'"
    fmt.Println("calc.Add(1, 2) => ", result)
}
```

```golang
// main/go.mod

module github.com/codelabstudios/main

go 1.14

require github.com/codelabstudios/core v0.0.0-00010101000000-000000000000

replace github.com/codelabstudios/core => ../core
```

```golang
// core/calc/math.go

package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/codelabstudios/core/calc"
)

func main() {
    result := calc.Add(1, 2)
    fmt.Println("calc.Add(1, 2) => ", result)
}
```

```golang
// core/calc/go.mod

module github.com/codelabstudios/core

go 1.14
```

Comment: You folder structure is nonsensical and does not match your modules and your packages. Read How to Write Go Code and stick to it.

Comment: @Volker I have 2 modules "core" & "main", the tree structure was a bit off with the "go.mod" file placement & I updated that. The repository will give you a better idea. I'm placing modules outside of $GOPATH because that approach is too restrictive.

Comment: First the `go.mod` should be at project level i.e at the level of `core` and `main`. Second I don't see any repository by `github.com/codelabstudios/core/calc`. Were you trying to import the `Add` function of you're own `core` pkg `https://github.com/webberwang/go-lint-error/blob/master/core/calc/math.go#L3`.

Comment: @TanveerAlam `core` and `main` are the modules, the project level just opens those modules. That repo doesn't exist because I'm using local module import

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some digging, I found out that the "replace" directive is part of the Vgo proposal (the V stands for versioning). This was merged with Go in 1.11.

To fix the local module import error, we just need to enable "Vgo Integration" in the IDE.

[image]